# How do I combine two files into one?

Tags: awk

i have 2 and possibly more files to process. 
file 1:

```
20150115,6601,30,4303.60,751,9000707480,20141201,TM985761,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000001
20150115,6601,30,4303.60,751,9000707480,20141201,TM951728,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000002
```

file 2:

```
20150115,6601,30,2400.00,751,9000707845,20141201,TM960897,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000003
20150115,6601,30,2400.00,751,9000707845,20141201,TM946939,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000004
```

so how to combine these files into

file 3:

```
20150115,6601,30,4303.60,751,9000707480,20141201,TM985761,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000001
20150115,6601,30,4303.60,751,9000707480,20141201,TM951728,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000002
20150115,6601,30,2400.00,751,9000707845,20141201,TM960897,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000003
20150115,6601,30,2400.00,751,9000707845,20141201,TM946939,6870904569,USD,FX0000000000000000000004
```

by now, im unable to process multiple files using below

```
cd /npcs/Rel2A/PROD/inbound/FXCSV/received
for i in `ls -l *.csv.dat | awk '/^-/ {print $NF}'`
do
cp $i /npcs/Rel2A/PROD/inbound/FXCSV/bckp_files/$i.orig
      echo $i
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}'  $i  > fxcsv00.dat
```

please help

Comment: Do you REALLY need to provide sample input with 20 fields per line? Why not lines like `a,b,c` in file1 and `A,B,C` in file2 so we've got less irrelevant information to wade through to see what your problem actually is and the output clearly shows what came from which input file?

Answer (score 2):

Given your posted sample input/output all you need is:

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to substitute the ">" with a ">>"

```
cd /npcs/Rel2A/PROD/inbound/FXCSV/received
for i in `ls -l *.csv.dat | awk '/^-/ {print $NF}'`
do
cp $i /npcs/Rel2A/PROD/inbound/FXCSV/bckp_files/$i.orig
      echo $i
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf "%-20s", $i};printf "\n"}'  $i  >> fxcsv00.dat
done
```

Comment: Never do that as it's got some fundamental shell issues (mainly parsing `ls` output and unquoted variables) which will cause you all sorts of bizarre errors in various situations.

Comment: Correct. I intended to answer on the specific question cause I don't know what's behind. I also think it's enough a simple cat.